# executereader:connection property not initialized error VS 2010

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, connection, desktop-application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WareHouseManagementSystems
{
class connection
{


public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
public SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
public SqlDataReader dr;

public void connect()
{
try
{

con.ConnectionString ="Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\WAREHOUSEMANAGEMENTSYSTEMS_VS2008\\WAREHOUSEMANAGE MENTSYSTEMS_VS2008\\DATABASE\\2008\\WAREHOUSEMANAGEMENT.MDF;Integrated Security=True;Connect  Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
con.Open();
com.Connection = con;
com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
}
catch
{

}


}

 public bool isValidEmail(string inputEmail)
 {
 string strRegex = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
 @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" +
 @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$";
 Regex re = new Regex(strRegex);
 if (re.IsMatch(inputEmail))
 return (true);
 else
 return (false);
 }
 }
 }
```

Whenever I debug it I get an error saying

> executereader: connection property not initialized

I tried checking the connection path everything is changed to the desired path or the location. But all in vain.

Comment: Is that really how your code is formatted? I wouldn't expect so. Please format the code in your post so that it's easier to read. Also, do you really have an empty catch block? That means you can't see any errors when you open the connection - that may well be the problem...

Comment: It will be also useful to see the code that calls ExecuteReader.

Comment: Also, get rid of that try/catch block. Keep the code inside the try, but get rid of the block - you are ignoring exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** Your connection string is not valid as there is no space between `Data` and `Source`.

```
                         |
                         >
con.ConnectionString ="DataSource=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=
```

**Solution:** you should have the space between `Data` and `Source` in your connection string.

Replace This:

```
con.ConnectionString ="DataSource
```

With This:

```
con.ConnectionString ="Data Source
```

**Suggestion :** You should never supress the catch block with `catch{}` otherwise it defats the whole purpose of having try catch blocks in your code.

Try This:

```
try
{
//some code here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
//some exception raised
Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Data source iv put separately only.it just got pasted unappropriately in the coloumn. i tried the second suggestion too but dat too dint worked :(

Comment: @user3343059: okay, can you try with this connection string `"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\WAREHOUSEMANAGEMENTSYSTEMS_VS2008\\WAREHOUSEMANAGE MENTSYSTEMS_VS2008\\DATABASE\\2008\\WAREHOUSEMANAGEMENT.MDF;Integrated Security=True;`